# Short to Int conversion

Tags: android, integer, int, converters, short

I am looking for a way to convert a Short to an Int. I tried to cast it with

```
short i = 5;
int t = (int) i;
```

But this doesn't work. Also in the Short function itself I cannot see something like an toInt() function...

Comment: what do you mean by not working ? you have done the casting already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The follow code can be a (not elegant) solution of your problem:

```
short i = 5;
int t = 0;
t = t+i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at "[Short](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Short.html)" the wrapper class?